# VSE script for to add constant gaps between strips?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

How to **add equal distance** between the selected strips ?

Is there a **script to access strips** it will be great ?

Note: The I am aware or **Shift** + **=** to remove the gap between strips
I want to do the reverse of it I want to add equal space

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I turned your question into [one of my example scripts](http://web.purplefrog.com/~thoth/blender/python-cookbook/vse-strip-gap.html).  I'll include it inline because that's how stackexchange works:

```
import bpy


def gap_strips(strips, gap):
    strips = sorted(strips, key=lambda strip: strip.frame_start)

    cleanup = []
    for i in range(1, len(strips)):
        st0 = strips[i-1]
        st1 = strips[i]
        cleanup.append( [ st1, st1.channel ])
        st1.frame_start = st0.frame_start + st0.frame_final_duration + gap
    # blender's anti-overlap code might change the channel.  put it back.
    for x in cleanup:
        x[0].channel = x[1]

def gap_selected_strips(gap):
    gap_strips( bpy.context.selected_editable_sequences , gap)


gap_selected_strips(15)
```

Comment: it makes some strips jump up channels

Comment: This should probably operate on `bpy.context.selected_editable_sequences`, so it doesn't behave strangely while inside meta-strips.

Comment: Hopefully the latest version fixes the shortcomings you both identified.

Answer (score -1):

Improvised from *@Mutant Bob* script. Thanks *@Mutant Bob*

## the perpose of this script is to add a same amount of gap between all the clips or reduce the gap with same amount

## Please select all the clips before running the script

```
import bpy

def gap_strips(strips, gap):
    strips = sorted(strips, key=lambda strip: strip.frame_start)
    
    if ( gap > 0 ):
        for i in range(len(strips)-1,0,-1):
            st1 = strips[i] 
            st1.frame_start = st1.frame_start + gap*i
    elif ( gap < 0 ):
        for i in range(0,len(strips)):
            st1 = strips[i] 
            st1.frame_start = st1.frame_start + gap*i
    elif ( gap == 0):
        for i in range(1,len(strips)):
            st0 = strips[i-1]
            st1 = strips[i] 
            print(st0.frame_start + st0.frame_final_duration,st1.frame_start)
            st1.frame_start = st0.frame_start + st0.frame_final_duration


def gap_selected_strips(scn, gap):
    gap_strips(
        [strip for strip in scn.sequence_editor.sequences if strip.select],
        gap)


gap_selected_strips(bpy.context.scene, 20)
```