# How to list strips in Blender VSE?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Suppose the duration of the listed strips changed during the project.
You will need to refresh and rearrange the strips.

[image]
In Blender, this seems to be a manual task.

[image]
But After Effects has the ability to automatically align strips.
(I've attached an example of AE to help you understand what I want.)

I want to know if Blender VSE has the same functionality as After Effects's `keyframe assistant-sequnce layers`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select all of your strips you want to put in order and run this script:

```
import bpy

strips = bpy.context.selected_editable_sequences
strips = sorted(strips, key=lambda strip: strip.frame_final_start)

cleanup = []
for i in range(1, len(strips)):
    st0 = strips[i-1]
    st1 = strips[i]
    cleanup.append( [ st1, st1.channel ])
    st1.frame_start = st0.frame_start + st0.frame_final_duration
for x in cleanup:
    x[0].channel = 1
strips[0].channel = 1
```

[image]
It's a version of this script: [VSE script for to add constant gaps between strips?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27740/vse-script-for-to-add-constant-gaps-between-strips/27763#27763)

Comment: Amazing power and possibilities of the script. 
I want to learn Blender Python.

Comment: Nice work! And a great example of simple scripting in the VSE