# Quickly stack strips horizontally in VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor

So i just dragged in a couple of strips like this:

[image]

And i want to stack them horizontally like this:

[image]

I want to import a sequence of PNGs and there are more than a hundred of them... Is there any quick way to do this without having to manually drag each strips?

Comment: There is a small script for this here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/154436/37272